# Boot order gets reset after every restart

Tags: windows, boot, bios, updates, reset

Hi I am having this issue after a bios update. I have a ssd and a hdd both containing windows( I imaged from hdd to sdd after buying the laptop). Before the update, the machine used to boot from ssd. After the update it is booting from hdd inspite of resetting the boot order from bios menu. I have tried setting and saving the boot menu to sdd first several times, but it gets reset to hdd after restarting.

Bios version : EMCN44WW.
DEVICE : IDEAPAD 3 15IILO5.

I have windows 10 loaded BTW.

Comment: how old is this box? could the cmos battery have gone bad?

Comment: Cmos is ok. It's just couple of months old. Besides time is ok. The problem happened just after the bios update.